# group by clause flask alchemy

Tags: sql, flask, sqlalchemy

```
sample = {
        '13-18':50,
        '19-25':60,
        '25-40':50,
        '50-80':100

    }
```

I want to find the count of users who fall in the above mentioned categories, that is from age `13-18, 19-25` respectively , how would i query using *SQLalchemy* , i am having only ***date of birth*** field to work with

```
dob : 07/10/2005
```

*DOB* is in above mentioned format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add more details. What is your database (postres, mysql, other?)? Depending on DB, there are different set of builtin functions. And what the type of column `dob` is? Is it a string or a datetime.
In postgreSQL your implementations could be:

```sql
select 
case 
    when age < 13 then '0-12'
    when age >= 13 and age < 25 then '13-25'
    when age >= 25 and age < 40 then '25-40'
    when age >= 41 and age < 80 then '41-80'
    else '80+'
end as range,
count(*)
from (
  SELECT 
  1 + extract('years' from justify_interval(now() - to_date(dob, 'DD/MM/YYYY'))) as age 
  from table
) x
group by range
```

You can rewrite it to sqlalchemy syntax, but it is tricky. You can also use raw sql execution in sqlalchemy, like:

```py
from sqlalchemy.sql import text

statement = text(<sql_above>)
result = session.execute(statement)
```

Comment: my db is `PostgreSQL`, and dob has date in `DD/MM/YYYY` format i assume its string which has come from MongoDB,  @jorzel

Comment: So this solution should work for you, It is for postgres.

Comment: yes it worked you're a saint @jorzel just had to replace `table name`